# Namespace '"appwrite"' has no exported member 'Team'.ts(2694)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, appwrite

I am creating a whatsapp clone using vue and appwrite as Baas but while doing I encountered with the error "Namespace '"appwrite"' has no exported member 'Team'.ts(2694)".

```
<template></template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Models} from 'appwrite';

interface Props {
    chats: Models.Team[];
}

defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

I checked on the appwrite modules installed and yet no change
but when i created a folder type\appwrite and created a index.ts file and written down this code

```
export{Team}from appwrite;
```

yet nothing changed.

Comment: That's odd that you're getting that error...What version of the SDK do you have? Also, what's `moduleresolution` set to in your `tsconfig.json`?